# Codeigniter Join on string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a select statement that work correctly as a standalone query and I am trying to make it work in code igniter (without using the db->query function) and the problem is that I cant seem to find away to do a join with the constraint being a string. Joining on two columns works great but a column and a string is a no go for me

Well here is was I got.
Working standalone query

```
join html_attribute_value as hav on he.id = hav.html_element_id
join html_attribute as ha on ha.id = hav.html_attribute_id
join html_attribute_value hav2 on hav2.attr_value="header_logo"
join html_attribute ha2 on ha2.attr = 'id';
```

Note the last 2 lines how they are compared to a hard-coded string

Now in Codeigniter Iv got

```
$this->db->join("html_attribute_value as hav2","hav2.attr_value = \"header_logo\" ");
$this->db->join("html_attribute as ha2","ha2.id = \"id\"");
```

This does not work. I have also tried reversing the quotes so

```
$this->db->join("html_attribute_value as hav2",'hav2.attr_value = \'header_logo\' ');
$this->db->join("html_attribute as ha2",'ha2.id = \'id\'');
```

This does not work. I have also tried no quotes

```
$this->db->join("html_attribute_value as hav2",'hav2.attr_value = header_logo ');
$this->db->join("html_attribute as ha2",'ha2.id = id');
```

This does not work. I have also tried reversed quotes

```
$this->db->join("html_attribute_value as hav2",'hav2.attr_value = "header_logo" ');
$this->db->join("html_attribute as ha2",'ha2.id = "id"');
```

Any tips? If not i will resort to just using $this->db->query('long query string here');

Is there a way i can use parameters in a join

```
$this->db->join("html_attribute as ha2",'ha2.id = ?');
```

Using a where clause will not work as these joins are being used as a subquery, if that makes any sense if not trust me XD.

And here is the error for the geniuses

```
Error number: 1064 / You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '` 
JOIN `'html_attribute` as ha2 ON `ha2`.`id` = "`id"`'
```

Comment: You have problem with quotes, double qoutes and backticks as error message can be read. Try to change it similar to this `$this->db->join("html_attribute as ha2","ha2.id = 'id'");` Use double quotes if you need to [interpolate variable](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) like `$this->db->join("html_attribute as ha2","ha2.id = $id");` or `$this->db->join("html_attribute as ha2","ha2.id = {$id}");`. Beside that you can pass your plain query to `$this->db->query("QUERI TEXT YOU FOUND WORKING")`.